# getting data from angular js

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

I am trying to get data from back end server in angular. I have a java servlet which fetches data from database based on html input field and returns the response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script>
            "use strict";
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

            app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.cityArray = ["hyderabad", "secunderabad", "delhi", "mumbai"];
                $scope.submit = function ($event) {
                    if ($scope.myForm.$invalid) {
                        // Or some other update
                        $scope.myForm.$submitted = true;
                        $event.preventDefault();
                    }
                };
            });
            app.directive('uniqueUsername', function ($http) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                        element.bind('blur', function (e) {
                            ngModel.$setValidity('unique', true);

                            $http.post('CheckUserName.do', element.val()).success(function (data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    ngModel.$setValidity('unique', false);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h2 class="text-muted">Registration form</h2>
        <div>
            <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" novalidate>
                First name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="uname" unique-username="" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span>
                <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted && myForm.uname.$error.required">Please fill field above<br></span><br/>
                <span style="color:red" class="hide-while-in-focus" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.unique">Username already exist<br/></span>
                <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="submit($event)">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is `request.getparameter("uname")` is always returning null. Right now I can see in the chrome console that angularjs is able to communicate with the servlet but the response is null as username passed is being null.

Here's the java servlet code:

```
public class CheckUserName extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        String username = req.getParameter("uname");
        System.out.println(username);

        try {
            Connection con = OracleDBConnection.getConnection();
            String selectQuery = "select FIRSTNAME from registration";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(selectQuery);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String firstName = rs.getString("FIRSTNAME");
                if (username.equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
                    resp.getWriter().write("username already exist");
                    req.setAttribute("errMsg", "username already exist");
                    RequestDispatcher rd2 = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index4.jsp");
                    rd2.forward(req, resp);
                } else {
                    resp.getWriter().write("username available");
//                    req.setAttribute("errMsg", "");
//                    resp.sendRedirect("EmailConfirmation.jsp");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("DB related Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$http.post()` method expects an object and not string. Try changing your code to:

```
$http.post('CheckUserName.do', {
    data:  "uname=" + element.val()
}).success(function (data) {
    if (data) {
        ngModel.$setValidity('unique', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Still its taking it as null. Here's the error:
`null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.In10s.CheckUserName.CheckUserName.doPost(CheckUserName.java:44)`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specify a request parameter name in post method call:

```
   $http.post('CheckUserName.do', element.val()).success
```

You need to change above line to :

```
    $http.post('CheckUserName.do',{uname:element.val()}).success
```

Comment: Still it takes it as null

Comment: Can you debug and check what you are getting in element.val()

Comment: In chrome console, It is showing the username typed but when it comes to servlet, it says null

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        $http.post(url, {
         "uname": value
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         //success
         }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         //error
        });
```

The input you are passing to the service should be like this.

Comment: what is `"value"` in "`uname: value"` ??

Comment: value is the actual data you are sending.In your case it is the username.

Comment: The problem is I am able to send data from front end but the servlet is not able to retrieve the value as in when I use `request.getParameter("name");`